# Matplotlib fig.canvas.renderer works on Win, fails on Mac

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have this function shown below. It receives a Numpy array that contains a live image captured by the system camera, the shape is typically (480, 640, 3). The function draws a few rectangles and labels on the image, using Pyplot. It then tries to extract the annotated image back into a Numpy format, and displays it with CV2.

```py
def draw_boxes(imdata, v_boxes, v_labels, v_scores):
  # load the image
  #data = pyplot.imread(filename)
  # plot the image
  fig, ax = pyplot.subplots()
  ax = pyplot.imshow(imdata)
  # get the context for drawing boxes
  ax = pyplot.gca()
  # plot each box
  for i in range(len(v_boxes)):
    box = v_boxes[i]
    # get coordinates
    y1, x1, y2, x2 = box.ymin, box.xmin, box.ymax, box.xmax
    # calculate width and height of the box
    width, height = x2 - x1, y2 - y1
    # create the shape
    rect = Rectangle((x1, y1), width, height, fill=False, color='red')
    # draw the box
    ax.add_patch(rect)
    # draw text and score in top left corner
    label = "%s (%.3f)" % (v_labels[i], v_scores[i])
    ax.text(x1, y1, label, color='white', bbox=dict(facecolor='blue', alpha=0.3))
  fig.canvas.draw()
  #pyplot.show()
  annotated = np.array(fig.canvas.renderer.buffer_rgba(), dtype=np.uint8)
  pyplot.close('all')
  cv2.imshow('camera', cv2.cvtColor(annotated, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
```

Python 3.7, Matplotlib 3.1.1, OpenCV 4.1.1.26, Numpy 1.16.4 - I use the same versions on all my systems.

The function works great on Windows 10, I even get a decent framerate out of it.

On macOS 10.14.6 I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sentry.py", line 278, in <module>
    draw_boxes(cvRGBimage, v_boxes, v_labels, v_scores)
  File "sentry.py", line 193, in draw_boxes
    annotated = np.array(fig.canvas.renderer.buffer_rgba(), dtype=np.uint8)
AttributeError: 'FigureCanvasMac' object has no attribute 'renderer'
```

Why is it different?

Comment: What backend are you using with matplotlib?

Comment: @Marc I just added matplotlib.use('TKAgg') at the top of the file and it's now fixed on Mac, but I have yet to verify it on Windows.

Comment: Yeah that was what I was going to suggest ;) nice you found it yourself!

Comment: @Marc That did it - works on Windows too. Thanks!

Comment: If you have time maybe add an answer so other people know what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was easy. I just had to add one line after importing the matplotlib module:

```py
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TKAgg')
```

It tells matplotlib to use the TKAgg backend, which seems to avoid the error on Mac.